# How to start jupyter notebook server with a bat file in windows (7,10)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, jupyter-notebook

I have a bat file that I can run by click on it with the mouse. That activates a conda environment starts a server and calls webpage. Though the after execution the bat file closes and the server is shut down as well. How can I make the server persisting?

```
call activate myenv
jupyter notebook --no-browser
start "" url.html
```

Under Linux I would probably send the jupyter process into the background by adding `&` sign.

Comment: Because the the server is running and app that needs to be accessed through that url. There is a notebook extension called Appmode.

Comment: But then the website is not opened right? Also, the server is not persisting.

Comment: It works in the anaconda prompt, but not when I start the script with cmd.exe. Conda is not known. and `call activate` is not recognized as internal or external command. Can I tell the bat file that it should be started with the anaconda prompt?

Comment: ok, that is different, I misunderstood the question then,

Comment: You mean I should call the website before the server is opened? Replacing both lines?

Comment: That works. But only when I open the `anaconda prompt`. Can I call the anaconda prompt from with cmd.exe? Or tell the bat file that it needs to be opened with anaconda prompt?

Comment: When you run the Anaconda Prompt it is creating a cmd.exe environment with several Anaconda specific environmental variables defined. That is why it works from the Anaconda Prompt and not a regular batch file.

Comment: But I don't want to have to start the anaconda prompt and run the script manually. I want to click on the script with the mouse, done. Conda is generally not in the `PATH`.

Comment: Your batch file has no idea where `activate.bat` exists if the path to the bat file is not in the `PATH` environmental variable.  You would need to give it the full path to all the programs you want to execute.

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to use the full path to `Activate`. `call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate myenv`. The environment should be set from there and then you should also use `CALL` with `JUPYTER`. `CALL jupyter notebook --no-browser`.

Comment: That is exactly what happens. The file does not know where activate is. I am looking for a way to tell the script to use anaconda prompt, without telling it where it is. Cause the conda installation may be different for each user on different systems. Or even the same system.

Comment: And the standard installation path also depends on the windows version...

Comment: I guess the solution is to not use anaconda but virtual env.